# Laravel/Pusher - WebSocket is closed before the connection is established

Tags: laravel, pusher

I'm trying to make a notification system, I install everything, but return this error:

> WebSocket connection to
>   'ws://ws.pusherapp.com/app/XXXXXXXXXXXXX?protocol=7&client=js&version=4.2.2&flash=false'
>   failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.

And sometimes return this too:

> WebSocket connection to
>   'ws://ws.pusherapp.com/app/XXXXXXXXXXXXX?protocol=7&client=js&version=4.2.2&flash=false'
>   failed: Invalid frame header

Someone knows what's happening?

Answer (score 1):

Try downgrading pusher.js from 6 whatever to

```
"pusher-js": "^4.3.1"
```

Comment: I faced this issue but i am using pusher verison 3.0 Any tips?

Answer (score -1):

Recently, I had faced this problem so I have searched in google but could not find the solution then I have applied the below code myself and it is started working fine. I thought this might be useful to some others who are facing the same error that why I have pasted this answer here.

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo"
window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'pusher-key',
    cluster: 'ap2',
    encrypted: true
});
```

After that you need to run the command - `npm run dev` and hope it will work for other. If encrypted true is not working then you can use false for local development.